# Weekday number regardless of the NLS settings

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking for the simplest way to determine  the weekday number for the `DATE` value in oracle  independent of the  `NLS` settings.

```
Monday  -> 1
Tuesday -> 2
…
Sunday  -> 7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do NLS settings change the output of:  `select to_char(to_date('03/09/1982','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY')` ?

Comment: @Goat_CO: yes, try    `alter session set nls_language='russian'; select to_char(to_date('03/09/1982','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY') from dual;`

Comment: I don't have an oracle instance to play around on, just curious, it returns different names for the days?  Can you use comparison to day 0 to ferret out which day of the week it is, or does that vary by NLS settings too?

Comment: @Goat_CO Try SQLFiddle.com

Comment: You can alter session in SQLFiddle? Surprising.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ISO weeks start on Monday; they don't use NLS settings. I *think* this expression is reliable.

```
1 + trunc(your_date) - trunc(your_date, 'IW')
```

To show how the arithmetic works . . . current_date is a Wednesday.

```
select current_date as cur_date
     , trunc(current_date) as trunc_cur
     , trunc(current_date, 'IW') as trunc_iso
     , trunc(current_date) - trunc(current_date, 'IW') as date_diff
     , 1 + trunc(current_date) - trunc(current_date, 'IW') as dow
from dual

CUR_DATE                    TRUNC_CUR                  TRUNC_ISO                   DATE_DIFF  DOW
June 19 2013 16:01:51+0000  June 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 June 17 2013 00:00:00+0000  2          3
```

In general, if you can't find an expression that reasonably does what you expect, you can always use a table. (And, perhaps, a function that isolates SQL from the underlying implementation.)

So you can always use something like

```
create table weekday_numbers (
  weekday char(3) not null primary key,
  weekday_num integer not null unique
    check(weekday_num between 1 and 7)
);

insert into weekday_numbers values ('Mon', 1);
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  `1 + trunc(your_date) - trunc(your_date, 'IW')`  done it. The option with a table is not suitable in my case, since the day names are language specific.

Comment: @schurik - you could use the optional [third *nlsparam* parameter in `to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm) to force the day name for your date to a fixed language, independent of the session settings; which you could then join to the table. If you preferred the table route, that is.

Comment: i'm just writing to say how awesome and _elegant_ this solution is, too bad it's a bit verbose, buuuuuut.... I'll take it like this happily. Go global environments and **NO** NLS dependent code!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the remainder of the difference in days between the date in question and the date of a known Monday (eg 1900-01-01).

```
mod(my_date-date '1900-01-01',7)+1 day_of_week
```

You'd have to choose a suitably ancient Monday such that all the dates you'd use are greater than or equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

I use `MOD(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'J'), 7)` (or +1 if you please). [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a115b9650cb12c4735d127486fcc9710)

J stands for *Julian day; the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC*.